# Understanding the idea of asyncAndWait

Tags: multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have found some API lacking documentation and I'm hoping someone out there understands what it's about.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/3656285-asyncandwait

```
asyncAndWait(execute:)
```

This sounds like an oxymoron. Surely waiting on the thread that dispatched this means it was dispatched sync (not async)?

Comment: The [documentation for the C version of the API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/3191901-dispatch_async_and_wait) may shed some light.

Comment: Also see the comments in [the header file](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-1173.0.3/dispatch/queue.h.auto.html) and the explanation in [this Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/pedantcoder/status/1135938715098857477).